# Google Maps Api Marker setOptions() change icon

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I want to change a marker icon when selected by a drawed polygon. In addMarker() the markers are parsed from JSON data and push into allMarkers array. The icon is red when not selected and would become white when selected.

```
function addMarker(lat,lng,i){
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        icon: "http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png",
        map: map
    });
    marker.shapeId = '0';
    allMarkers.push(marker);    
}   


function selectMarkersInPoly() {
    alert(allMarkers.length)
    for (var i=0; i < createdShapes.length; i++) {
        for (var j=0; j < allMarkers.length; j++){
            var latlong = allMarkers[j].getPosition();
            if(google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(latlong, createdShapes[i]) == true) {
                allMarkers[j].shapeId = createdShapes[i].id;
                allMarkers[j].setOptions({
                    icon : "http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_white.png"
                });
            }
        }
    }   

}
```

What is wrong with selectMarkersInPoly() ??? Thank you for your help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not the correct syntax for a javascript anonymous object:

```
allMarkers[j].setOptions({
                icon = "http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_white.png"
            });
```

(I would think you would get javascript errors in the javascript console) 
This should work:

```
allMarkers[j].setOptions({
                icon: "http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_white.png"
            });
```